# Swap JButton Icons On MouseClicks

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have a `JButton[][]` array that stores every button on a grid.
What I want to do is :

1) click the `jbutton(icon)` that I want to move on the grid.

2) click on the jbutton that I want the previous selected jbutton(icon) to move to.

```
private class BListener implements MouseListener { 
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        JButton but = ((JButton) e.getSource());
        if(iconSelected && !but.equals(selectedButton)){ // move(swap) buttons
            but.setIcon(selectedButton.getIcon());


            selectedButton.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
            selectedButton.setName(null);
            selectedButton=but;
            iconSelected=false;
        }else if(!iconSelected && but.getName()!=null){ 
            iconSelected=true; 
            selectedButton=but;
            but.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.YELLOW,3));
        }else{ 
            if(iconSelected){
                System.out.println("Already Selected");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Not selected");
            }
        }

    }
```

I have tried some things that didnt work ( this moves the icon but the icon also remains at the starting location). Any insight would be helpfull.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you never change the `selectedButton`'s icon, Try this:

```
if(iconSelected && !but.equals(selectedButton)){ // move(swap) buttons
        Icon bIcon = but.getIcon();
        but.setIcon(selectedButton.getIcon());
        selectedButton.setIcon(bIcon);
        ...
}
```

Comment: Yes although i have another problem this exactly answers the question!.
Thank you.